Excel VBA ADODB connection with parameters error: The variable name '@...' has already been declared

The variable name '@P10' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

When I execute this code below, above error comes on my SQL parameters @P10 at line Set oRS = .Execute:
Sub SalveazaFactura(ByRef vRaspuns As Variant, ByRef vParametri As Variant)
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    Dim strMyQuery As String
    
     strMyQuery = "SET NOCOUNT ON; " & vbCrLf & _
                    "DECLARE @P01 bigint = ?; DECLARE @P02 char(3) = ?; DECLARE @P03 nvarchar(50) = ?; DECLARE @P04 date = ?; DECLARE @P05 bigint = ?; " & vbCrLf & _
                    "DECLARE @P06 decimal(12, 2) = ?; DECLARE @P07 char(3) = ?;  DECLARE @P08 nvarchar(255) = ?; DECLARE @P09 nvarchar(255) = ?; DECLARE @P10 nvarchar(50) = ?; " & vbCrLf
     If vParametri(1) = 0 Then
        strMyQuery = strMyQuery & _
                    " INSERT INTO [iScalaDB].[dbo].[CONTA_RegistruDocumenteIntrare_test] " & _
                    " ([Tip Document],[Nr Document],[Data Document],[Cod Emitent],[Valoare],[Moneda],[Stare 1],[Format 1],[Localizare 1],[Observatii 1],[Data Inregistrare 1],[Username 1]) " & _
                    " VALUES (@P02, @P03, @P04, @P05, @P06, @P07, 'C00', 'F00', 'L00', @P09, GETDATE(), @P10); " & vbCrLf & _
                    " SET @P01 =  CAST(scope_identity() AS bigint); SET @P05 =  CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS bigint); " & vbCrLf & _
                    " UPDATE [iScalaDB].[dbo].[CONTA_RegistruDocumenteIntrare_test] SET [Nume fisier] = RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @P01), 6) + @P08 WHERE [ID] = @P01; " & vbCrLf & _
                    " SELECT @P05 AS 'Rows', @P01 AS IDOut; "
     Else
        strMyQuery = strMyQuery & _
                    " UPDATE [iScalaDB].[dbo].[CONTA_RegistruDocumenteIntrare_test] " & _
                    " SET [Tip Document] = @P02, [Nr Document] = @P03, [Data Document] = @P04, [Cod Emitent] = @P05, [Valoare] = @P06, [Moneda] = @P07, " & _
                    " [Nume fisier] = @P08, [Observatii 1] = @P09, [Data Inregistrare 2] = GETDATE(), [Username 2] = @P10  WHERE [ID] = @P01; " & vbCrLf & _
                    " SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Rows', @P01 AS ID; "
     End If
     
    Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection: Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oCM As ADODB.Command: Set oCM = New ADODB.Command
    Dim dbADOParameter As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Err As ADODB.Error

    oDB.Open gcConn & "; Collation=Latin1_General_CI_AS"
    If Not oDB.State = adStateOpen Then
        MessageBoxW Application.ActiveWindow.hWnd, StrPtr(Sheet3.Range("Mesaj004").Value), StrPtr("Eroare!"), 16
        GoTo Err_Execute
    End If
    
    With oCM
        .ActiveConnection = oDB
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .Prepared = True
        .NamedParameters = True
        .CommandText = strMyQuery

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P01", adBigInt, adParamInput, 20, vParametri(1))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P02", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 3, vParametri(2))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P03", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, vParametri(3))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P04", adDate, adParamInput, 7, vParametri(4))
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P05", adBigInt, adParamInput, 20, vParametri(5))
         Set dbADOParameter = .CreateParameter("@P06", adDecimal, adParamInput, 14, vParametri(6))
            dbADOParameter.Precision = 12: dbADOParameter.NumericScale = 2
        .Parameters.Append dbADOParameter
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P07", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 3, vParametri(7))
        If vParametri(8) = "" Then
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P08", adWChar, adParamInput, 4, Null)
        Else
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P08", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, vParametri(8))
        End If
        If vParametri(9) = "" Then
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P09", adWChar, adParamInput, 4, Null)
        Else
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P09", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, vParametri(9))
        End If
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P10", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, vParametri(10))
        
        Set oRS = .Execute
    End With
    
    If Not oRS.BOF And Not oRS.EOF Then
        vRaspuns = oRS.GetRows()
    Else
        vRaspuns = Array(-1, 0)
        GoTo Err_Execute
    End If
    
    oRS.Close
    Set oRS = Nothing
    oDB.Close
    Set oDB = Nothing

Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
{...}
End Sub


I exported strMyQuery and ran the query in SSMS without any errors
I checked the information in the parameter collection of the oCM object and everything is fine: there are no two parameters with the name @P10 and each parameter has the correct value
I have checked the solutions given for other questions related to the same error, but they are NOT applicable in this case: the parameters are declared one by one without a loop.


You are declaring Parameters with the same names as your SQL Variables - but you haven't used named parameters in your SQL string. Instead of @ P01 to @ P10 try @ Parm1 to @ Parm10

Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean when you say "but you haven't used named parameters in your SQL string."

If it was an error that the ADODB connection parameter has the same name as the SQL variable, the error at @P01 should have appeared, not quite at the end...
In addition, I have other situations where fixed on the same model works normally.
In the present situation there is a problem but I can't figure out which one!

You have .NamedParameters = True but are using "DECLARE @P01 bigint = ?;  etc. That question mark is the parameter holder and has not been named. Parameters must be supplied in the correct order.
As to your other comment - how do you know it would deal with the Parameters in the order 1 to 10 and not last to first?

Instead of .NamedParameters = True and DECLARE @P01 bigint = ?; how should I declare the parameters in strMyQuery so that the parameters are named?"
I came to this solution following another question on Stackoverflow, from which I understood that ADODB always requires the use of ? as a  parameter holder. I did not understand well?

"Parameters must be supplied in the correct order."
For this reason I use DECLARE @Pnn = ? in order of parameter number. Is not enough?
